# Vnecoms Vendor Flate Rate Shipping Carrier with such method not found: vflatrate_test3||19, vendor_multirate

Tags: magento2.2, shipping-methods, marketplace

I am using Vnecoms marketplace and VENDOR MULTIPLE FLATRATE SHIPPING addons for shipping.

https://www.vnecoms.com/magento2-marketplace/plugins/vendor-multi-flatrate-shipping.html

In the Shipping step after selecting shipping methods for the vendor, I'm getting the error as below.

Carrier with such method not found: vflatrate_test3||19, vendor_multirate

Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: As your module is paid if you have remain support of this module, you can also raise the ticket in support, they have to solve your problem

Comment: support period expired so i can't take help from them.